# CPU time and wall clock time

Tags: performance, time

curious question on timing. When measuring wall clock time  with any language such as python `time.time()` does the time include the CPU/System  `time.clock()` time in it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `time.time()` gives you the elapsed time (also known as wall time).That includes CPU time inasmuch as that's a subset of wall time but you cannot extract CPU time from `time.time()` itself.

For example, if your process runs for ten seconds but uses the CPU for only five of those seconds, the former includes the latter.